# Using data from callback outside of function

Tags: node.js

Using a function to make a http request with NodeJS. Passing a previously defined array as argument when running the function but the array is empty when console logged.

```
var testList = []:

var httpQuery = function(ep, q, lst) {
  ep.selectQuery(q).then(function (res) {
       return res.json()
  }).then(function (result) {
        lst = result.results.bindings;
  }).catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err)
  })
};

httpQuery(endpoint, testq, testList);
```

How can I get the data from the function callback in to my previously defined array and use it outside of the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score 2):

If you were console.logging 'testList' after calling httpQuery, then of course it would be empty. httpQuery is asyncronous, (and reassigning `lst` inside the fucntion wouldn't have worked anyway).

To take care of asyncronous promise-based functions, you have to return the promise and use `.then()`

```
var httpQuery = function(ep, q) {
  return ep.selectQuery(q).then(function (res) {
       return res.json()
  }).then(function (result) {
        return result.results.bindings;
  }).catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err)
  })
};

httpQuery(endpoint, testq)
    .then(list => {
        console.log(list)
    });
```

[edit] Depending on what version of node you're using, you may be able to use async/await. The above code is essentially equivalent to

```
async function httpQuery(ep, q) {
    try {
       let res = await ep.selectQuery(q);
       let result = await res.json();
       return result.results.bindings;
    } catch(e) {
       console.error(e);
    }    
}

(async () => {
    let testList = await httpQuery(endpoint, testq);
    console.log(testList);
})();
```

Comment: Works fine, but still unable to use the data outside of : httpQuery(endpoint, testq)
    .then(list => {
        console.log(list)
    });

Comment: @Znowman if I think I understand what you mean by 'outside of', then you will *never* be able to get it to work 'outside' of that, because these are asyncronous calls. You will only ever be able to get access to the result of httpQuery inside of a `.then` or `await` following the call of the httpQuery function. What you're asking for is impossible.

Comment: @Znowman and more importantly, you're mistaken for thinking you have any reason to *need* to access it the way you think you do. Whatever logic you have that uses the result of httpQuery *can be run just fine* after awaiting the result, or running it inside of a `.then`